# Uploading Content From A textarea On To A Folder

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am currently working a code that will upload the contents of a textarea as .html file into a folder named uploads. I would like for the php script to run when the user presses share.

```
<a id="wshare" class="btn">Share</a>

<textarea id="icontent" placeholder="Enter your content here." name="mas" rows="15" class="content"></textarea>

<?php
error_reporting(0);
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
  $errors= array();
  $file_name = rand(5, 1000000);
  $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
  $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
  $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
  $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

  $expensions= array("html");
  if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
    $errors[]="Only Html Files can be uploaded!";
  }
  if($file_size > 2097152){
  $errors[]='Sorry,Looks Like Your File Is Larger Than 2MB =(';
  }
  if(empty($errors)==true){
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$file_name);
    echo "Success-Link: uploads/" .$file_name;
  }else{
    print_r($errors);
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Answer (score 1):

I guess you know that php and javascript aren't executed at the same time not the same "place" and cant be used together as you seems like you're intenting.

IMO you should ask the user for a filename at the moment your form get submitted, fill a hidden input field with the answer, then combine both of the values (textarea + hidden input field) in php

Comment: I have removed the file name part. Is it possible to just upload texarea content into a folder in html format?

Comment: Folder or file ?

Comment: You can use `file_put_contents` to write inside a file

Comment: Sorry, i meant to say folder.

Comment: Ok, so juste create the dir if it does not existe (`mkdir`) and create the file

Comment: Can you provide an example? If I knew what you were talking about I wouldn't be asking for help.